# sqlalchemy: table with columns defined based on first line of a csv file

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlalchemy

I want to create a database using sqlalchemy which read from the csv and generate the table where the column names and numbers are taken from the csv first line, the column values are the taken from the other lines. I need a table constructor not defined at compilation time but at runtime.

the following code is an extract

```
meta = MetaData() 


engine = create_engine("my_pattern",echo = True)

meta.create_all(engine)

Base = declarative_base() 
class dataset_reference(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'dataset_reference'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    # Add other columns based on your CSV file's structure
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            column_name = key.strip().replace(" ", "_")
            column_name = column_name.strip().replace(":", "_")
            setattr(self, column_name, value)


with open('myfile.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
       dataset_table = dataset_reference(id='0', **dict2add)
       Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
       Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
       session = Session()
       session.add(dataset_table)

session.commit()


session.close()
```

The result is the same, I read from command line using mysql command in a terminal and the table has only the ID column.
I have tried to add another column "manually", like the id, and the table has the two columns, but it never takes columns from the csv file

Thanks!!

Comment: You can use pandas' [read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to load the CSV file into a DataFrame, then use [to_sql()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) to write the DataFrame to your table.

Comment: Uhm thanks i didnt know to_sql function, but for me it is also an excuse to study some slq and sqlalchemy. Anyway, thanks for your advice